# Blogger Blogspot different header1 image for Mobile from Desktop

Tags: blogger

looking to show a different background image on my mobile template theme versus the desktop theme on blogger/blogspot blog.

Currently it is showing the same image uploaded for the desktop theme in Layout/Header1 Widget.

The code snippet below shows the Header1 Widget. I would like to A: Use an image to replace the blog title and description; and B: Use a different image for mobile versus desktop.

I'm looking at the !--Show Image Only area and unsure how to add an if: data:blog.isMobile

```html
<header>
    <div class='header-outer'>
    <div class='header-cap-top cap-top'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    <div class='fauxborder-left header-fauxborder-left'>
    <div class='fauxborder-right header-fauxborder-right'/>
    <div class='region-inner header-inner'>
      <b:section class='header' id='header' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'>
        <b:widget id='Header1' locked='true' title='Wisconsin Explorer (Header)' type='Header'>
          <b:widget-settings>
            <b:widget-setting name='displayUrl'>http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2Pq9AO4eOJY/Wa30DFl96xI/AAAAAAAAIBs/QaONXMPNVS8ww6IjNgrn7jNUtAEkgQeeQCK4BGAYYCw/s1600/desktop%2Blogo.png</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='displayHeight'>225</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='sectionWidth'>752</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='useImage'>true</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='shrinkToFit'>false</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='imagePlacement'>REPLACE</b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='displayWidth'>1100</b:widget-setting>
          </b:widget-settings>
          <b:includable id='main'>

  <b:if cond='data:useImage'>
    <b:if cond='data:imagePlacement == &quot;BEHIND&quot;'>
      <!--
      Show image as background to text. You can't really calculate the width
      reliably in JS because margins are not taken into account by any of
      clientWidth, offsetWidth or scrollWidth, so we don't force a minimum
      width if the user is using shrink to fit.
      This results in a margin-width's worth of pixels being cropped. If the
      user is not using shrink to fit then we expand the header.
      -->
      <b:if cond='data:mobile'>
        <div id='header-inner'>
          <div class='titlewrapper' style='background: transparent'>
            <h1 class='title' style='background: transparent; border-width: 0px'>
              <b:include name='title'/>
            </h1>
          </div>
          <b:include name='description'/>
        </div>
      <b:else/>
        <div expr:style='&quot;background-image: url(\&quot;&quot; + data:sourceUrl + &quot;\&quot;); &quot;                      + &quot;background-position: &quot;                      + data:backgroundPositionStyleStr + &quot;; &quot;                      + data:widthStyleStr                      + &quot;min-height: &quot; + data:height                      + &quot;_height: &quot; + data:height                      + &quot;background-repeat: no-repeat; &quot;' id='header-inner'>
          <div class='titlewrapper' style='background: transparent'>
            <h1 class='title' style='background: transparent; border-width: 0px'>
              <b:include name='title'/>
            </h1>
          </div>
          <b:include name='description'/>
        </div>
      </b:if>
    <b:else/>
      <!--Show the image only-->
      <div id='header-inner'>
        <a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' style='display: block'>
          <img expr:alt='data:title' expr:height='data:height' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_headerimg&quot;' expr:src='data:sourceUrl' expr:width='data:width' style='display: block'/>
        </a>
        <!--Show the description-->
        <b:if cond='data:imagePlacement == &quot;BEFORE_DESCRIPTION&quot;'>
          <b:include name='description'/>
        </b:if>
      </div>
    </b:if>
  <b:else/>
    <!--No header image -->
    <div id='header-inner'>
      <div class='titlewrapper'>
        <h1 class='title'>
          <b:include name='title'/>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <b:include name='description'/>
    </div>
  </b:if>
</b:includable>
          <b:includable id='description'>
  <div class='descriptionwrapper'>
    <p class='description'><span><data:description/></span></p>
  </div>
</b:includable>
          <b:includable id='title'>
  <b:tag cond='data:blog.url != data:blog.homepageUrl' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' name='a'>
    <data:title/>
  </b:tag>
</b:includable>
        </b:widget>
      </b:section>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='header-cap-bottom cap-bottom'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    </div>

    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `data:blog.isMobileRequest` instead of `data:mobile`

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest'>
  <div style='background-image: url(
https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-fTbhFqMEXwQ/WaYHi3JaowI/AAAAAAAAH9c/Xc1iTWjGzvQSMNutcKvrud3s8bk2b4ijwCKgBGAs/mobile
%2Blogo.png);background-position:left ; min-height:400px ;_height:400px ;background-repeat: no-repeat;&quot;' id='header-inner'>
    <div class='titlewrapper' style='background: transparent'>
      <h1 class='title' style='background: transparent; border-width: 0px'>
        <b:include name='title'/>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <b:include name='description'/>
  </div>
<b:else/>
  <div expr:style='&quot;background-image: url(\&quot;&quot; + data:sourceUrl + &quot;\&quot;); &quot;                      + &quot;background-position: &quot; + data:backgroundPositionStyleStr + &quot;; &quot; + data:widthStyleStr + &quot;min-height: &quot; + data:height + &quot;_height: &quot; + data:height + &quot;background-repeat: no-repeat; &quot;' id='header-inner'>
    <div class='titlewrapper' style='background: transparent'>
      <h1 class='title' style='background: transparent; border-width: 0px'>
        <b:include name='title'/>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <b:include name='description'/>
  </div>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Thank you Bassam for taking the time to look at my question. Your answer did not solve the issue. The desktop image is still showing on both desktop and mobile. I've looked further at the code I inherited and found that I wasn't looking at the right header option. I want to use the images instead of the blog title and description. Now I am even more confused about how to get an if isMobile setup. I am going to edit the code in my question above to provide the full picture of the Header1 Widget.